# Why does react-native's onLayout occur in a random order in ios?

Tags: ios, react-native

Why does react-native's onlayout return in a apparently random order when used in array.map on IOS devices?

I'm using onlayout in a function that returns a number of touchableopacity components, based on a array of objects. It finds the first one which has not yet passed and then stores its position to scroll to it using the following code:

```
renderScrollViewContent () {
var data = this.state.dataSource.topics[this.state.TopicID].programs
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 7}}>
    {
        data.map((l, i) => (
          console.log("B:" + l.title),
          <TouchableOpacity key={i}
            onLayout={event => {
              console.log("C:" + l.title)
              if (this.state.scrollPosition === 0 && Moment().isBefore(l.end_time)) {
                const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout
                this.state.scrollPosition = layout.y  
                ...
```

The problem is that while B: is always in the same order, C: is different each time, like its being drawn async, but only on IOS devices - android testing shows the same each time.

Is there a way I can get it to act sync or otherwise get the y position of the first array element whose end time has not yet passed? And what is the difference between the way ios and android utilises onlayout?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem so I fixed by creating a new array as a temp and sort it

```
  const handlingEnter = (e, index) => {
        data.push({index,width: e,})
        data.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)
        console.log(data)
  }

  <View
    onLayout={(event) => {
    handlingEnter(event.nativeEvent.layout.width, index)
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const setCoordinates = (event, itemIndex) => {
      console.log('itemIndex:', itemIndex)
      // and your logic of itemIndex
   }

items.map((item, index)=> {
   return (
      <View
         key={index}
         onLayout={(event) => setCoordinates(event, index)}
      >
        <Text>TextExample<Text>
      </View>
   )

})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.